# Leaf.XNet C# Sending Body as Json not working

Tags: c#, json, api, dropbox-api

```
HttpRequest httpRequest = new HttpRequest();
RequestParams reqParams = new RequestParams { };
httpRequest.IgnoreProtocolErrors = true;

reqParams["data"] = "{\"path\": \"/Prime_Numbers.txt\"}";
httpRequest.AddHeader("Authorization", " Bearer MYKEY");
httpRequest.AddHeader("Content-Type", "application/json");

Console.WriteLine(httpRequest.Post("https://api.dropboxapi.com/2/sharing/create_shared_link_with_settings", reqParams).ToString());
```

Im getting the following error: Error in call to API function "sharing/create_shared_link_with_settings": request body: could not decode input as JSON. I am using the dropbox api.

I saw the following: https://github.com/csharp-leaf/Leaf.xNet/issues/66 (Someone had a similar issue, but this fix did not work)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you are using `RequestParams` that means `Context-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded`.
You can't set `Content-Type` via `.AddHeader()`, use argument for `.Post(url, json, contentType)` method like this:

```cs
HttpRequest httpRequest = new HttpRequest();
httpRequest.AddHeader("Authorization", " Bearer MYKEY");

string url = "https://api.dropboxapi.com/2/sharing/create_shared_link_with_settings";
string jsonData = "{\"path\": \"/Prime_Numbers.txt\"}";
string response = httpRequest.Post(url, jsonData, "application/json").ToString();

Console.WriteLine(response);
```

Comment: Thank you, this worked!